# implementation of Exploring Randomly Wired Neural Networks for Image Recognition?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Is there any implementation of the paper Exploring Randomly Wired Neural Networks for Image Recognition by tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the paper(Exploring Randomly Wired Neural Networks for Image Recognition) with pytorch which support multi-machines training. You only just configure the hyperparameters to get up and running. Visit 
 https://github.com/JiaminRen/RandWireNN